# How can I disable the bottom taskbar?

Tags: 17.10, gnome-shell, window, taskbar, gnome-tweak-tool

[image: screenshot with taskbar along the bottom of the screen]

I want to know how to make the taskbar at the bottom of the screen disappear.

This taskbar appeared after I installed some theme. How can I make that taskbar disappear?

I thought this was editable in `gnome-tweak-tool`, but I can't find the relevant tab.

(It's not the Dock that's installed by default in Ubuntu)

OS: Ubuntu 17.10 Artful Aardvark

Answer (score 3):

In `gnome-tweak-tool` turn `Window list` off

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I am confused. Because my gnome extension and window list were already disabled, and I enabled the extensions and check off that window list option but it doesn't disappear.. anyway, Thanks a lot! and sorry for that my question was one of many same question.